# I keep getting http POST http://localhost:3000/api/authenticate 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, express

*am using angular 6 and express when am developing this api on authentcate uri it returning Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/api/authenticate: 404 Not Found*

*i have tried removing of the responses on my user.controller.js but the problem persisits it seems am missing out some point here and i dont know here it is at first i got an error saaying cant send headers after they are sent and the error was on my user.controller.js on this line else return res.status(404).json(info);*

**Here is my user.controller.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const passport = require('passport');
const _ = require('lodash');


module.exports.register = (req,res, next) => {


    const user = new User();
    user.fullname = req.body.fullname;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.College = req.body.College;
    user.Department = req.body.Department;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.admintype = req.body.admintype;
    user.save((err, doc) => {
        if(!err) { res.send(doc)}


        else
        {
            if(err.code == 11000)
            res.status(422).send(['Duplicate email Address Found.'])
            else
            return next(err);
        }
    }) 
}

module.exports.authenticate = (req, res, next ) => {
    //calll for passport authentication
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
        //error form paasport middleware
        if(err) return res.status(400).json(err);
        //registered user
        else if (user) return res.status(200).json({ "token":user.generateJwt() });
        //unknown user or wrong password
        else return res.status(404).json(info);
    })(req, res);
}

module.exports.userProfile = (req, res, next) =>{
    User.findOne({ _id:req._id},
         (err,user) =>{
             if(!user)
             return res.status(404).json({ status: false, message : 'User Record not Found. '});
             else
             return res.status(200).json({  status:true , user : _.pick(user, ['fullname','email','university','College','Department','admintype'])});
         } );

}
```

**Here is my user.service.ts**

````
```import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './user.model';
import{ HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import{ environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  selectedUser: User = {
    fullname:'',
    email:'',
    university:'',
    College:'',
    Department:'',
    password:'',
    admintype:''
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postUser(user:User)
  {
    return this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl+ '/register' ,user)
  }

  login(authCredentials)
  {
    return this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl+ '/authenticate',authCredentials);
  }

  setToken(token:string)
  {
    localStorage.setItem('token',token);
  }
}```
````

**Here is my sign-in.components.ts**

````
```import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/shared/user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private userService:UserService, private router:Router) { }

  model = {
   email:'',
   password:''
  };

  emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/


  serverErrorMessages : string;
  ngOnInit() {
  }


  onSubmit(form :NgForm)
  {
   this.userService.login(form.value).subscribe( 
     res =>{
      this.userService.setToken(res['token']);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/signup');
   },
   err =>{
     this.serverErrorMessages = err.message;

   });
  }
}```
````

**Here is my environment.ts**

````
```/ This file can be replaced during build by using the `fileReplacements` array.
// `ng build --prod` replaces `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts`.
// The list of file replacements can be found in `angular.json`.

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiBaseUrl:'http://localhost:3000/api'
};

/*
 * For easier debugging in development mode, you can import the following file
 * to ignore zone related error stack frames such as `zone.run`, `zoneDelegate.invokeTask`.
 *
 * This import should be commented out in production mode because it will have a negative impact
 * on performance if an error is thrown.
 */
// import 'zone.js/dist/zone-error';  // Included with Angular CLI.```
````

**Here is my auth.js**

````
```const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../controller/model/User');
const ctrlUser = require('../controller/user.controller');
const jwthelper = require('../jwtHelper')


//validation

router.post('/register', ctrlUser.register);
router.post('/authenticate',ctrlUser.authenticate);
router.get('/userProfile',jwthelper.verifyJwtToken,ctrlUser.userProfile);



module.exports = router;```
````

**Here is my index.js**

````
```const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('./passportConfig');
const passport = require('passport');

dotenv.config();


//connect to mongodb
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false); mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT,{ useNewUrlParser:true} , () =>
console.log('connected to db!')
);

//import routes
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');

//middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(passport.initialize());

//error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) =>{
    if(err.name =='ValidationError')
    {
        var valErrs = [];
        Object.keys(err.errors).forEach(key => valErrs.push(err.errors[key].message));
        res.status(422).send(valErrs);
        next();
    }
});


//route middleware
app.use('/api',authRoute);



app.listen(3000, () => console.log("server Up and Running"));```
````

**Any Help please on this one please thank you all**

Comment: have you setup any routes to point api to correct path e.g. https://itnext.io/building-restful-web-apis-with-node-js-express-mongodb-and-typescript-part-3-d545b243541e

Comment: yes let me add the path to the question

Comment: You're asking about a route that returns 404 (not found), but you don't show us a single route definition on your server.  If you're requesting the right URL in your client, then that's likely where the problem is on your server.  We need to see that code or the credentials are failing.  It seems you should be able to first debug where the route is failing and show that specific code.

Comment: okay let me add it on the question @jfriend00

Comment: i have added everything @jfriend00

Comment: Have you already config cors for nodejs ?

Comment: yah sure brother surprising is that register uri works fine though its the authenticate which fails brother @TonyNgo

Comment: Doesn't seems like, you have a route for **/api/authenticate** which can accept the **POST** request. Might be you have for **Get** not for **Post** request.

Comment: @VikrantSingh yes it is a post request look at my user.controller.js or what am i missing brother

Comment: and it works fine on postman @VikrantSingh

Comment: @VikrantSingh i have updated my question to show that its a post request

Comment: Try to compare the postman request with the request you are actually sending out from your angular app (with console.log or debugging). Maybe the payload is not correct

Comment: can you include your main file (index, server or app.js) ?

Comment: yes @SuleymanSah i have added it there already

Comment: thanks guys i did it i was trying to sign in with the user who is not authenticated

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which is remain is to attach the router which you have define in the `auth.js` file to your express app like this

```
const authRouter = require('./auth');
```

And to prefix all routes define in the `auth.js` file you attach it as a middleware which is trigger on route prifix with `\api`
    const express = require('express');

```
const app = express();

// define all your middleware and all other route

// and here you attach the auth router
app.use('\api', authRouter);
```

This will make authentication available on url `http://localhost:3000/api/authenticate`

Comment: i have updated my question by adding the index.js i still do not see the problem because the register url works fine or could eleborate more sir soory am newbie in api dev

Comment: i think thats added on my index.js

Comment: and whats surprises me is that the register url works fine but not the authenicate

Comment: when you are call the authenticate endpoint do you use POST method or get?\

Comment: thanks guys it finally did it i was trying to login the user who was not autheticated

Comment: You are welcome, happy to hear that your issue is fixed

Answer (score 0):

You may also get 404 because of this line in authenticate route (by the way I think this must be a 400 - bad request, not 404, which is making confusion.)

```
else return res.status(404).json(info);
```

So to understand this, can you replace your authenticate route like this, and see what logs in the api console:

```
module.exports.authenticate = (req, res, next ) => {
  console.log("req.body: ", req.body)
  //calll for passport authentication
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
      //error form paasport middleware
      if(err) return res.status(400).json(err);
      //registered user
      else if (user) return res.status(200).json({ "token":user.generateJwt() });
      //unknown user or wrong password
      else {
        console.log("info: ", info)
        return res.status(400).json(info);
      }
  })(req, res);
```

Also it the angular component, can you change your onSubmit like this for easy debug:

be sure your form.value is correct:

```
  onSubmit(form :NgForm)
  {
    console.log("form.value: ", form.value);

   this.userService.login(form.value).subscribe( 
     res =>{
      this.userService.setToken(res['token']);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/signup');
   },
   err =>{
     console.log("err: ", err.message)
     this.serverErrorMessages = err.message;

   });
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much can you help me on role redirection  in the same app

Comment: @KyleMutta I am happy that your problem is resolved, can you consider accepting my answer?

Comment: If you don't know how to accept answer, please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @KyleMutta  if you think this answer helped you, please consider accepting it as an answer.